# How do I link code together in R such that sequential steps run?

Tags: r

I am trying to link code together such that each step runs sequentially. The input of each step requires the output of the previous one. For loops do not work and pipes do not either. I am using the package xcms for pre-processing omics data.

```
##Initial preparation
 cdfs <- dir(system.file("cdf", package = "faahKO"), full.names = TRUE,
        recursive = TRUE)[c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12)]
 phenodat <- data.frame(sample_name = sub(basename(cdfs), pattern = ".CDF",
                               replacement = "", fixed = TRUE),
             sample_group = c(rep("KO", 4), rep("WT", 4)),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 ##Steps 
 peaky <- xcmsSet(files=cdfs, phenoData= phenodat, method="centWave",
                  peakwidth=c(20,80), snthresh=10, noise=5000, prefilter=c(6, 5000))
 alig <- retcor(peaky, method="obiwarp", plottype="deviation")
 groupy <-  group(alig, bw = 20, mzwid=0.015)
 fill <- fillPeaks(groupy)
```

Any suggestions for automatically linking these steps would be greatly appreciated. The aim is to ultimately submit one R script as a "batch" job in a HPC.

Comment: If you source the above script then all the computations _will_ be carried out in sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure if that what you mean, but you can put the code between `{ }` this way it will run it all at the same time

Comment: If all those commands are in a a script file, then you can run them with `Rscript myscript.R` or whatever you name the file There's no need to change the code at all. There's no need to create multiple script files.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you, I didn't realise that it would run through the script sequentially, without some sort of modification to the code. Will just make sure the order is correct before finalising script.